# Adding an embed Youtube video inside HTML <a></a> tag

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

When I adding a youtube video to my webpage This is working.

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

But I want to add video in following way.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" class="my-popup-video">
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-play-circle-outline zmdi-hc-fw"></i>
</a>
```

But then it look likes [image]

How can I fix this. Any help !

Comment: please explain what you're doing? What is not working?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just using an a-tag. This is a link to the url, that is specified with `href=""`
To play a Video directly in your page, you have to use `<iframe>` or `<video>`